# contact form 7 captcha support any other captcha plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, captcha

I am Using wp & I installed Contact form7. Now I want to Add Captcha with Contact form7. I don't like "Really Simple Captcha" because it shows very simple images. Any other Captcha Plugin Support Contact form7? I need Like the output of "SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam" or "Fast Secure Contact Form", Here Unfortunately I can't Remove Contact form7 Plugin. So I want to Add Captcha Plugin with my Contact form7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SweetCaptcha!
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sweetcaptcha-revolutionary-free-captcha-service/

If you need any help , drop them a mail to :
support@SweetCaptcha.com

http://www.SweetCaptcha.com

Cheers,
Josh

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html

Answer (score 0):

This plugin requires an account on their website.